# Need to show only current employees in an Excel On-demand Report

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, spreadsheet, vba

I've prepared a spec for a new report for a client (.net development) to generate an excel report.

Each row in the report relates to an employee. Some of the example columns in the Report are things like: Employee ID, Start Date, TerminatedDate, Salary, Paycode etc.)

The client wants custom filters on the on-demand report screen in our web application to be able to:

- See current employees (i.e. where termination date is NULL)
- See employees who have been terminated in the current financial year (i.e. between the termination dates of 01/01/2017 and 30/06/2017, inclusive)

Now we could do this, but the problem is the time and money to implement it as it will affect all clients and she requires this filter on only one report.

I was going to suggest she simply generate the excel report and add filters from within Excel to narrow down on the employees that meet the above two conditions.

I came up with different excel formulas (just randomly experimenting at the moment), such as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F8), "yes","no")
```

And

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(F5),MONTH(F5), DAY(F5)) > DATE(2017,1,1) AND(DATE(YEAR(F5),MONTH(F5), DAY(F5)) < DATE(2017,6,30)), "yes", "no")
```

Now needless to say the above are wrong.
Can anyone please advise me of the formula that can filter the records based on the above conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use DATE(YEAR(F5),MONTH(F5), DAY(F5))? Is TerminatedDate not a date?

Comment: It's a date.
Was trying to use the function since =DATE(F5) did not work.
It's format is DATE(year, month, day)

Comment: Can you post an example of a date in F5?

Comment: Correct implementation of second formula `=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(F5),MONTH(F5), DAY(F5)) > DATE(2017,1,1),(DATE(YEAR(F5),MONTH(F5), DAY(F5)) < DATE(2017,6,30))), "yes", "no")`